# Find duplicate symmetric rows in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which contains data as

```
col1  col2  
a      b  
b      a  
c      d
d      c
a      d 
a      c
```

For me row 1 and row 2 are duplicate because `a, b` & `b, a` are the same. The same stands for row 3 and row 4.

I need an SQL (not PL/SQL) query which gives output as

```
col1   col2
a       b
c       d
a       d
a       c
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select distinct least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2)
from your_table
```

Edit: for those using a DBMS that does support the standard SQL functions `least` and `greatest` this can be simulated using a CASE expression:

```
select distinct 
       case 
         when col1 < col2 then col1
         else col2
       end as least_col, 
       case 
         when col1 > col2 then col1
         else col2
        end as greatest_col 
from your_table
```

Comment: least and greatest aren't any functions in SQL server can you provide any solution for SQL too ?

Comment: @yogi: those are standard SQL functions (the question is for Oracle). If SQL Server is that limited you'll have to use a CASE expression to get the bigger and the smaller value.

Comment: bigger and smaller ?? I didn't get it how can I compare `a` and `b` these aren't numerals they are string(character) type, are you talking about there ASCII values comparison ??

Comment: @yogi, Oracle can compare characters, see here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE t_1(col1 varchar(10),col2   varchar(10))

INSERT INTO t_1
VALUES ('a','b'),  
('b','a'),  
('c','d'),
('d','c'),
('a','d'),
('a','c')

;with CTE as (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 0)) as id,col1,col2,col1+col2 as col3 from t_1)
,CTE1 as (
select id,col1,col2,col3 from CTE where id=1
union all
select c.id,c.col1,c.col2,CASE when c.col3=REVERSE(c1.col3) then null else c.col3 end from CTE c inner join CTE1 c1
on c.id-1=c1.id

)

select col1,col2 from CTE1 where col3 is not null
```

Comment: That is invalid syntax for Oracle, mainly because of the multi-row insert (but Oracle also needs the statement terminator `;` at the *end* of a statement, not at the beginning)

Comment: This solution is for SQL server 2005 or higher versions.

Comment: You did see the `oracle` tag? (and there is a much simpler solution for SQL Server)

Comment: Yeah I saw the solution for SQL server and I did not see Oracle tag.